# An object or column name is missing while trying to load a text file into a sql table

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle, pyodbc

I am trying to import a data txt file into a sql table, using python script. The problem is that when i run the script it gives me an error that an object or column name is missing. and that i should verify each column in my query has a name. Now i am kind of lost what it means cause i already have made the table in the db and it has the column names. Kindly guide me on how to get past this error.

i cannot share the data i am trying to load cuase it has sensitive information. Hoping my code would be enough, following is my code:

```
with open(DEST_SRV_PTH) as infile:
for line in infile:
    data = line.split(",")
    query = ('insert into iru_temp_abd (sr_num,msisdn,notes) values (?%s,?%s,?%s)' % (str(fields[2:3]),str(fields[11:12]),str(fields[14:15])))
    cursor.execute(query, *data)
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Can you post the DDL of table iru_temp_abd also.

Comment: What is the value of `query` variable when you see this error? Is it possible that one of the values being inserted is blank?

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro u mean the design of the table?

Comment: @shahkalpesh i ll try to check

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahWajahat yes

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro there are 3 columns  sr_num,msisdn,notes all nvarchar(max) type.

Comment: @shahkalpesh i checked the values are ?[] so i am guessing this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 2 issues:

1. fields is probably a list and has no values in the selected positions. Try to print `fields[2:3]` and it will return an empty list. You have to resolve this first.
2. the variable query has an error in it, it should be:

   `query = ('insert into iru_temp_abd (sr_num,msisdn,notes) values (%s,%s,%s)' % (str(fields[2:3]),str(fields[11:12]),str(fields[14:15])))`

Comment: i have tried multiple combinations of the 2nd issue you raise i have tried:
  values(?,?,?)
and also values(%s,%s,%s) 
as for the first issue i will check it

Comment: as you said i fixed the these issue but now i have another error:
"The sql contains 0 parameter marker, while you are passing 3 parameter markers".

when i search this it the only solution i find is replacing values(%s) with values(?), any idea how do i solve the parameter error?

Answer (score 1):

Using string formatting to insert data into the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement is a dangerous practice because it leaves your code open to SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should use a proper *parameterized query*, e.g.,

```
sql = 'insert into iru_temp_abd (sr_num,msisdn,notes) values (?,?,?)'
params = (str(fields[2:3]),str(fields[11:12]),str(fields[14:15]))
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

or, if `data` really does contain the column values then just use

```
crsr.execute(sql, data)
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. I think the data format is the problem. does python parse special characters and spaces?

Comment: No, the actual characters in the parameter values are completely irrelevant. That's sort of the whole purpose of a parameterized query.